# Asp.Net Core Google authentication

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-sso

My app runs on Google Compute Engine. Nginx used as a proxy server. Nginx was configured to use SSL. Below is the content of /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mywebapp.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-mywebapp.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    root /home/me/MyWebApp/wwwroot;
    location /.well-known/ {
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I have:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"],
});
```

Now in Google Cloud Platform I need to specify Authorized redirect URIs. If I enter the following, my web app works as expected:

```
http://mywebapp.com/signin-google
```

But, it won't work if `https` is used; browser displays the following error:

```
The redirect URI in the request, http://mywebapp.com/signin-google, does
not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.
```

In this case, is it safe to use http as authorized redirect uri? What configuration do I need if I want it to be https?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This happens because your application which is running behind a reverse proxy server doesn't have any idea that originally request came over HTTPS.

**SSL/TLS Termination Proxy**

The configuration of the reverse proxy described in the question is called SSL/TLS Termination reverse proxy. That means that secure traffic is established between a client and a proxy server. The proxy server decrypts a request and then forwards it to an application over HTTP protocol.

The issue with this configuration is that an application behind it is not aware that client sent request over HTTPS. So when it comes to redirect to itself it uses `HttpContext.Request.Scheme`, `HttpContext.Request.Host` and `HttpContext.Request.Port` to build a valid URL for redirect.

**X-Forwarded-* HTTP Headers**

This is where `X-Forwarded-*` headers come into play. To let the application know that request is originally coming through a proxy server over HTTPS we have to configure the proxy server to set `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP headers.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

OK, now if we get back to ASP.NET Core application and take a look at incoming HTTP request we will see both `X-Forwarded-*` headers set, however a redirect URL still uses HTTP scheme.

**Forwarded Headers Middleware**

Basically this middleware overrides `HttpContext.Request.Scheme` and `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` to values which were provided by `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers appropriately. To make it happen let's add it to pipeline by adding the following line somewhere in the beginning of the `Startup.Configure()` method.

```
        var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
            RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
        };
        forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);
```

This should eventually make your application construct valid URLs with HTTPS scheme.

**My Story**

The code above looks different to what Microsoft suggests. If we take a look in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction) their code looks a bit shorter:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
     ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

However this didn't work for me. Also  according to the comments under [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384) I'm not alone.

I have a nginx set up as reverse proxy for ASP.NET Core application running in Docker container. It became more complicated after I put everything behind Amazon Load Balancer (ELB).

I followed advice from the documentation first, but it didn't work for me. I have got the following warning in my app:

> Parameter count mismatch between X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto

Then I looked at my `X-Forwarded-*` headers and realized that they had different length. `X-Forwarded-For` header was containing 2 records (comma separated IP addresses), while `X-Forwarded-Proto` only one record `https`. This is how I came up to setting the property `RequireHeaderSymmetry` to `false`.

Well, I got rid of 'Parameter count...' warning message, but immediately after that I faced another odd debug message:

> Unknown proxy: 172.17.0.6:44624

After looking into the source code of [ForwardedHeadersMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/rel/1.0.1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs) I have finally figured out that I have to either clean up both `KnownNetworks` and `KnownProxies` collections of the `ForwardedHeadersOptions` or add my docker network `172.17.0.1/16` to the list of known networks. Right after that I have finally got it working.

PS: For those who sets up a SSL/TLS termination on load balancer (e.g. Amazon Load Balancer or ELB) **DON'T** set header `X-Forwarded-Proto` in nginx configuration. This will override correct `https` value which came from load balance to the `http` scheme and redirect url will be wrong. I have not found yet how to just append scheme used in nginx to the header instead of overriding it.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I recently migrated a project from Core 1.0 to 2.0, and the custom middleware kludge in place from the old project no longer worked (it was a simple header check on context.Request that performed a `context.Request.Scheme = "https"`, based on the forwarded headers).  Your solution got our OAuth providers running again.

Comment: I confirm that as of current version, that can be found here:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/19ce3728871f462601510605c99b5d359190b19d/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs
still checks both KnownNetwors and KnownProxies thus the following code is still required:
            forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

Comment: This saved me tons of time (after spending tons of time). Removing Forwarded-Proto from the nginx sidecar next to my asp.net core app, which is behind a ssl terminating load balancer made the external logins work, by helping kestrel write urls with correct scheme!

Comment: @alexy for you, there is a beer waiting in Denver should you ever make it to this part of the world.

Answer (score 0):

For apache users, need to add only one header:
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

Firstly need to be sure that mod_headers is enabled.