# Change RedirectUri, Nginx and ASP.NEt Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nginx

I'm developing a web site with `ASP.NET Core 2` and `Nginx`. I want to add Google authentication.

Server is Linux, running Nginx, SSL enabled. ASP.NET is running on `http://localhost:5000/` and Nginx uses reverse proxy to access.

Problem is, when I try to access Google, URL schema is `http` because ASP.NET runs in http. And I get error saying "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" because `https` is defined on Google side.

I've tried `OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint` event and changed `RedirectUri` but not worked.

I've also tried changing `CallbackPath` to full URL but is said URL must start with `/`; it requires relative path.

Package I'm using is: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google (2.0.0)`

Any suggestions?

Service code is:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        options.CallbackPath = "/Login/GoogleCallback";
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint += context =>
        {
            context.Properties.RedirectUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri.Replace("http://", "https://");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        };
    });
```

Comment: This problem has been solved here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860128/asp-net-core-google-authentication/

Answer (score -1):

After adding these to config file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, it start working.

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
```