# Docker + Asp.net core api + Apache : infinite redirect loop

Tags: docker, apache, asp.net-core, ssl, debian

I am trying to containerize all things related to my web app (Asp.net Core API) using Docker Compose, including SSL Certificates (Certbot) on a VPS OVH Debian+Apache. I have an infinite redirect loop.

If anyone can spot where I am going wrong, I would be extremely grateful!

Docker-compose.yml :

```
my_app_prod:
        image: "myapp/my-app_prod:latest"
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "83:80"
          - "85:443"
        network_mode: bridge
```

[www.my-domain.com.conf](http://www.my-domain.com.conf) :

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.my-domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:83/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:83/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 www.my-domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.my-domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}helloapp-access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

[www.my-domain.com-le-ssl.conf](http://www.my-domain.com-le-ssl.conf) :

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-For" expr=%{REMOTE_ADDR}e
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.nicepet.fr
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:83/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:83/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 api.nicepet.fr


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.nicepet.fr/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.nicepet.fr/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Startup.cs :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<PathFilter>();
            services.AddDbContext<ApiNicepetContext>(item => item.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            
            services.AddControllers(mvcOptions => mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
            services.AddOData();
            //services.AddTransient();
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
                RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
            };
            forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);

            app.UseAuthentication();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
               
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
            app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
            {
                routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
                routeBuilder.Select().Filter().Expand();
                routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("OData", "odata", GetEdmModel());
            });
        }
```

Appsettings.json :

```
{
  "https_port": 443,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
//…
}
```

Program.cs :

```
//...
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseUrls("http://*:80");
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your application doesn't see that request is already coming over SSL because the reverse proxy you configured is responsible for SSL termination. It tries to redirect all requests to 443 with `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and it goes to the infinite loop.

Try to set up the `ForwardedHeaders` middleware like it's described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860128/asp-net-core-google-authentication/43878365?noredirect=1#comment112786821_43878365).

Comment: In this solution, it says to add code in startup.cs, which I have already done. Then it says add the "X-Forwarded-For" header, I added it but it still doesn't work.

"RequestHeader set" X-Forwarded-For "expr =% {REMOTE_ADDR} e" in www.my-domain.com.conf

Comment: Did you make sure to clean up the list of known proxies and networks? Did you set the RequireHeaderSymmetry to false?

Comment: Your Apache configuration doesn't show that it sets `X-Forwarded-Proto` for the `<VirtualHost *:443>`. That might be the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also please add your code to the original question instead of posting it as the answer.

Comment: If you don't need to redirect requests to https you can just remove the middleware `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` from your `Startup.cs`. If the issue in it that shall fix the redirection loop.

Comment: I commented app.UseHttpsRedirection() and now i have an 404 error.

Comment: It seems you are settings `https_port` setting in your `Program.cs` file. You don't actually need it because Apache manages everything related to setting up a secure network connection for your application already. Remove it and you can get the `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` middleware back if you want. As for the headers forwarding it's not necessary until you need to make a redirect to your own application and make sure it goes to the right domain and scheme which is not your case I guess.

Comment: I've just realized that you have set `https_port` in your `appsettings.json` file, not `Program.cs`. Remove and try to run it without it.